# website or app for sending notification for a location

Tags: android, ios, notifications

Is there a website or app for sending notification for a specific location?
I need to send notification and make it available for people in that location.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is one.
App download : https://terivi.page.link/29hQ? amv=1&apn=com.app.terivi&ibi=com.app.terivi&imv=2

Please check out https://terivi.com
It supports iOS and android.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuYvJ.png)